# Mousewheel Scroll Only Calling Previous

Tags: javascript, scroll, carousel, owl-carousel, mousewheel

I'm really stumped. I copied the mousewheel code directly from the owl carousel site ([here](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/mousewheel.html)). The only thing I changed was the id & variable names so I can have 2 carousels that scroll independently.

The problem is, the scroll is only calling prev.owl and not next.owl. I have a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oryxren/zugfqogs/#&togetherjs=4H391IhfDf). (I know having everything in the html is problematic, but for my site it has to be this way).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code for the mousewheel bit:

```
(document).ready(function(){
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
});

var owl1= $('#c1');
owl1.owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    nav:true,
    margin:10,
    responsive:{
         0:{
            items:1
         },
         600:{
            items:3
         },
         960:{
            items:5
         },
         1200:{
            items:6
         }
     }
};
owl1.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function(e){
     if(e.deltaY>0){
         owl1.trigger('next.owl');
     } else {
         owl1.trigger('prev.owl');
     }
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not know why but this code does help me to solve this issue.

```
owl[0].addEventListener('mousewheel', e => {
    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
      $('.owl-carousel').trigger('next.owl');
    } else {
      $('.owl-carousel').trigger('prev.owl');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  }, false);
```